# How to read from named pipe?

Tags: c, named-pipes

I want to create a server client communication through named pipe. Everytime something comes to a server,  I want to print the message and run server function - how do I only print when something gets sent? Could someone advise what I am doing wrong in the server file?

server

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int server(int d) { return d;}
int main()
{
 mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo1", 0666);
 char buf[256];

 for(;;) {
   
    int fd = open("/tmp/myfifo1", O_RDONLY);
    int rd = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(fd < 0) {
      perror("error: open");
    }
    if(rd < 0) {
      perror("error: read");
    }
    if(rd > 1 ) {
      printf("%s", buf);
    }
    server(5);
    close(fd);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

client

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf = "Hello from client";
    int fd = open("/tmp/myfifo1", O_WRONLY);
    int wr = write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(fd < 0) {
      perror("error: open");
    }
    if(wr< 0) {
      perror("error: write");
    close(fd);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code LGTM, what it's happening that is not expected? It didn't block at the read call in the server?

Comment: First of all add some error checking. Almost all functions you use can return with a failure that you must check. If a failure happens report it using e.g. `perror`.

Comment: BTW I wrote a small lib for having using fifos as way to monitor process from inside, it may work as an example for you https://github.com/dhilst/fifostats/blob/master/fifostats.h

Comment: Also, `&buf` is semantically wrong. You want to pass a pointer to the first byte of `buf`, which will be `&buf[0]`, or just plain `buf` (which *decay* to `&buf[0]`). The expression `&buf` gives you a pointer to the actual array, and it will have the type `char (*)[256]`.

Comment: On another note, when you write the buffer, you write *all* of the buffer, including the parts of it that might be left uninitialized (and with *indeterminate* values).

Comment: And as @geckos implies, the `read` function should block (not return) if there's nothing to be read from the pipe. It should only return once a "client" have sent something.

Comment: Note that for safety, you should use `if (scanf("%255s", buf) == 1)` and only use the content in the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: @CraigEstey — why `O_CREAT`?  If the FIFO doesn't exist, the code should not create an ordinary file.

Comment: @CraigEsteyNo, the `O_CREAT` option should not be used. If started in the right order the fifo file should have been created by the `mkfifo` function in the "server" program. And if started in the wrong order the "client" shouldn't create the file. The OP should however attempt to `unlink` the file in the "server" program before calling `mkfio`, if the file happens to exist.

Comment: On MacOS, the call `mkfifo("/tmp/fifo/", 0666)` fails because the trailing slash identifies a directory, not a FIFO (`errno == ENOTDIR`).  Removing the trailing slash fixes that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but how can I detect if a client has sent something and print the message on server terminal?

Comment: Simple: You "detect" it by the `read` function actually returning. If the `read` function returns, the client have sent something to be read, and you can print it or do whatever you want with the received data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've edited my post, the client seems to work, but I am not seeing any message in my terminal when Im running the server, what could be wrong?

Comment: You need to check if `mkfifo` fails as well. And it will fail if you have ran the server program at least once, because then the FIFO file will exists. Note above that I mentioned above that you need to `unlink` the FIFO file before calling `mkfifo`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I realised it doesn't print anything whenever I have the infinite loop. Why is this happening? Why does it force me to quit after sending one message? Also whenever I type `"hello world"` then in my terminal I only see `hello`

Comment: Now you're asking a whole set of new questions, that should be posted as such. But regarding the input question I can help you: I guess you use `scanf("%s", ...)`? Then you need to know that the `%s` format only read *space-delimited words*. If you want to read whole line use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: rearding: `int fd = open("/tmp/myfifo1", O_RDONLY);
    int rd = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(fd < 0) {
      perror("error: open");
    }
    if(rd < 0) {
      perror("error: read");
    }`  the call(s) to perror() only output  the current value of 'errno' not some prior value of 'errno'  Therefore, each call to errno must be immediately  after the statement that set the 'errno' value